# Is it grammatically correct to say "X person turned to Y person"?

Tags: sentence

Here are some examples:

> Erica turned to him
>
> Erica turned towards him
>
> Erica turned to face him
>
> Erica turned to look at him

I'm not sure if the first one is grammatically incorrect and/or ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are grammatical. The first however, can have a different meaning. While the last three examples all indicate a physical movement, the first can be more metaphorical. To *turn* to *someone* means to ask them for help.

> I couldn't understand the sentence, so I turned to ELU.

The previous sentence means that I asked ELU for help. The following sentence means that I physically turned my body

> I turned my face to the wall.

Comment: but perhaps in cases like this: "I'm sorry," he said, turning to her. "Turning" does not mean help?

Comment: You are quite right @janoChen. It depends on the context. In the absence of context, I at least, would understand  _he turned to her_ to mean he turned to her for help but it can take both meanings.

Answer (score 2):

All of those are equally correct grammatically, and all of them are in common usage.

> Erica turned to Adam and asked, "why did I turn to face you?"

Comment: Would it sound strange without the "asked"? (e.g. Erica turned to Adam. "Why did I turn to face you?").

Comment: No, omission of the *asked* or *said* introducing speech is very common, and increasingly so. It can leave one confused as to just who is saying what sometimes, but not here.

Comment: Jon's correct; in this context it's both grammatical *and* unambiguous in meaning.